# Passing data from controller into Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this comment controller:

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Article $article){
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->user_id = auth()->id();
        $comment->comment = request('comment');
        $comment->article_id = $article->id;
        $comment->save();
        return back();
    }
}
```

And it works. I tried to make my code cleaner by putting that logic into my model. So I changed it like this:

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Article $article){
        $article->addComment(request('comment'));
        return back();
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, in my Comment Model I'm doing like this:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','content','user_id'];

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function addComment($comment){
        Comment::create([
            'comment' => $comment,
            'article_id' => $this->id,
            'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
    }
}
```

but when I do this, I'm getting this kind of error:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment`, `article_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Test comment bla bla bla..., 1, 2017-10-16 09:27:27, 2017-10-16 09:27:27)) ◀"
```

It seems I can't get the `user_id` in that manner, so how can I pass the `user id` so i can insert it into my comment tables? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `user_id` to `$fillable` array in `Comment` model, not in `Article` model to make it work. Your original code works just because you do not use mass assignment there.

Comment: well you are right, i don't have to change anything. just add it into my fillable and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
\Auth::id()
```

instead of

```
auth()->id()
```

and go to your  database and and make `user_id` default as `NULL`

The reason for this kind of error is that laravel protects database fields for mass assignment when you add the following code it makes all fields fillable.

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Another way of doing is to add user_id in comments model. Is this case it will only allow the fields mentioned in the array to be mass assigned.

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'user_id'
    ];
```

Comment: add  protected $guarded = [];  in the comment model

Comment: but maybe u should adding it at your answer and i don't have to set user_id default into null.

Comment: if you declare that null it will still wont give you error because by default database will make user_id NULL :-)

Comment: no, currently my default is null, and i don't need to change anything like @Alexey said, i just need to put $fillable in Comment Model not just in my Article model. and it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   public function addComment($comment){
        Comment::create([
            'comment' => $comment,
            'article_id' => $this->id,
            'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id 
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: it give me Call to undefined method App\User::id() errors.

Comment: I guess, you're calling `\Auth::user()->id()` like this.

Comment: hahaha yeah i think so, but i still get the same errors, it say user_id doesn't have any value.

Comment: It  supposed to get the authenticated use id if the user is logged in.

Comment: yes that i confuse, when i using it in comment controller ive got no problem.